# Can I wait for an method and its internal executor/threads to finish before making an assertion on the test?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, executorservice, java-threads

I have a class that basically has this code:

```java
public class ManagerClass {
  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  void methodIWantToTest(/* params */){
    try {
      executor.execute(() -> {
        privateMethodINeedToWaitFor(/* params */);
        // Other stuff
      })
    } // catch
  }
}
```

I need to test this method (`methodIWantToTest`), and at the moment the assertion runs before `privateMethodINeedToWaitFor` has finished.
I don't know enough about threading to know if there's any way for me to wait for `methodIWantToTest` and every thread created within that method. The `privateMethodIHaveToWaitFor` updates some values that I need to check in my assertion.

I'm not comfortable refactoring this code yet as I'm not familiar enough with the codebase, so I would rather apply a solution on the test for the time being.

Currently on my test I do

```java
managerClass.methodIWantToTest(/* params */).
Thread.sleep(1000);
List<Things> list = managerClass.getListOfThings(); 
assertEquals(1, list.size()); 
// more assertions
```

which works as a way to check my test passes in my local environment, the sleep() seems enough. However I'd like my code to wait for the actual threads to be done, not just have an arbitrary sleep time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) library, which allows for constructs like

```
await()
 .atMost(30, SECONDS)
 .until(() -> managerClass.getListOfThings().size() == 1);
```

It will check the condition every 500 ms (adjustable default) and fail after the given at most time if not fulfilled.

One might argue it's syntactic sugar for something like

```
try {
 Instant latestEndTime = Instant.now().plusSeconds(30);
 boolean ok = managerClass.getListOfThings().size() == 1;
 while (!ok) {
  if (Instant.now().isAfter(latestEndTime)) {
   fail("condition not fulfilled after 30 seconds");
  }
  Thread.sleep(500);
  ok = managerClass.getListOfThings().size() == 1;
 }
} catch (InterruptedException x) {  // Thread.sleep() throws this
 fail("uh-oh - " + x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ExecutorService#submit(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) which returns a [`Future<?>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), on which you can call [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) which blocks until the `Runnable#run()` method has completed.

```
Future<?> methodIWantToTest(/* params */) {
    try {
        return executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                privateMethodINeedToWaitFor(/* params */);
                // Other stuff
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                // Handle here, otherwise it may be ignored if Future#get() is not called.
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } // catch
}
```

In your test:

```
managerClass.methodIWantToTest(/* params */).get();
```

In production code, the return value is ignored:

```
managerClass.methodIWantToTest(/* params */);
```